# for loop iteration with command substitution, not working when piping with cut

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to iterate through a list of IP's contained in a config file, but I need to cut lines, as I only need the IP and `conf=/path/to/file`, so I can throw those into an array or variable for further processing.

The problem is when adding a pipe to `cut -d$'\n' -f1,3` to the command substitution the for loop will only iterate one pass on the IP's in the `check` array list. DESIRED RESULTS AT BOTTOM.

Tried using xargs, but I'm having a difficult time with the output. I also tried awk, but I can't figure out how to use elements in an array to cycle through.  I'm open to ideas, as long as it's simple and best.

```
check=(
    "192.168.0.50"
    "192.168.0.100"
    "192.168.0.150"
    "192.168.0.200"
    )
for i in "${check[@]}"; do
    ip="$i"

    # config=$(grep -A2 "$ip" /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file)
    config=$(grep -A2 "$ip" /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file | cut -d$'\n' -f1,3)

    if [ -z "$config" ]; then
        echo "$ip NOT IN CONFIG"
    else
        echo "$config"
    fi
done
```

`config_file` contents

```
192.168.0.50
255.255.255.0
conf=/path/to/company/app/server001
logging=yes
-----
192.168.0.100
255.255.255.0
conf=/path/to/company/app/cluster
logging=yes
-----
192.168.0.50
255.255.255.0
conf=/path/to/company/app/server005
logging=yes
-----
192.168.0.150
255.255.255.0
conf=/path/to/company/app/server006
logging=yes
```

DESIRED RESULTS 2 passes produced in results for 192.168.0.50
KEEPING THE IPs SORTED or GROUPED, so duplicates are easy to spot.

```
192.168.0.50
conf=/path/to/company/app/server001
-----
192.168.0.50
conf=/path/to/company/app/server005
-----
192.168.0.100
conf=/path/to/company/app/cluster
-----
192.168.0.150
conf=/path/to/company/app/server006
```

Comment: Where do IPs in `check` come from? You write them manually or read from a source?

Comment: Sidenote, `for i in ...; do ip="$i"` should be `for ip in ...; do`

Comment: I edited the question and removed some trailing whitespace from the config file, but I don't think it affects the code.

Comment: `cut` already reads one line at a time; `-d $'\n'` isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Replace the `cut` with `grep -v 255.255.255.0` assuming that is always the second line of the three-line group and doesn't appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After the `grep -A2` you want lines 1 and 3. `cut` won't work, and this fails too:

```
config=$(grep -A2 "$ip" /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file | sed -n '1p;3p')
```

This will only return the first match of the `"$ip"`, you can better use `awk`.

You can convert your config file with

```
awk 'NR%5==1 {ip=$0} NR%5==3 {print ip " " $0}' config_file
```

and use this for your `grep` but you can better do everything in `awk` :

```
awk -v ip="${ip}" 'NR%5==1 {m=(ip==$0?1:0)} 
                   m && NR%5==3 {print ip; print $0; print "-----"  }' config_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-f1,3` only gets the first and third line, but you want every first and third line *in groups of three*.

Using awk, you can print each line matching `$ip`, then print the line two later.

```
for ip in "${check[@]}"; do
    awk -v IP="$ip" '($0==IP) {print; getline; getline; print; print "-----"}' config_file
done
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.50
conf=/path/to/company/app/server001
-----
192.168.0.50
conf=/path/to/company/app/server005
-----
192.168.0.100
conf=/path/to/company/app/cluster
-----
192.168.0.150
conf=/path/to/company/app/server006
-----
```

Comment: Thank you!  this is the answer I was looking for.  simple and direct.

Comment: @user11975370 Welcome! I just update the method a bit btw. If you found my answer the most helpful, please click the checkmark on the left to "accept" it.